# Copy array with pointers

Tags: delphi, lazarus, freepascal

I have array

```
type
Ttable=array[0..7] of ^TRecord;
var
table:Ttable;
```

I would like to create temporary tmp table with the same values, however, the temporary change does not affect the right one.

Could you help me?

Comment: You can create `table2` and copy all pointers from `table`. What are you going to do further?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have an array of pointers, but you want a temporary copy that you can manipulate without affecting the original records, is that correct?

Comment: @Dsm yes exactly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue that you have is that if you copy a table of pointers, the pointers still point to the original objects or records, and therefore any manipulation will affect the original data.

To avoid this you need to copy the original records, not the pointers to them. You indicate (but don't actually state) that you are using records rather than objects. The difference is the disposal of the newly created objects - for records you don't need  to, but for objects you do. In your case you might want to make the array permanat for future reuse.

To illustrate I added 3 memo fields to a form. Two notes - you need to create a second set of records somehow, and the important bit is **CopyTable**

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Unit3, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TRecord = record
    Something : integer;
  end;

  TTable = array[0..7] of ^TRecord;

  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Memo3: TMemo;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    Record0 : TRecord;
    Record1 : TRecord;
    Record2 : TRecord;
    Record3 : TRecord;
    Record4 : TRecord;
    Record5 : TRecord;
    Record6 : TRecord;
    Record7 : TRecord;
    TempRecord0 : TRecord;
    TempRecord1 : TRecord;
    TempRecord2 : TRecord;
    TempRecord3 : TRecord;
    TempRecord4 : TRecord;
    TempRecord5 : TRecord;
    TempRecord6 : TRecord;
    TempRecord7 : TRecord;
    fTempTable : TTable;
  public
    Table : TTable;
    { Public declarations }
    procedure CopyTable;
    procedure ShowTable( const ATable : TTable; const AMemo : TMemo );
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm2 }

procedure TForm2.CopyTable;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 7 do
  fTempTable[i]^ := Table[ i ]^;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Set up tables
  Table[0] := @Record0;
  fTempTable[0] := @TempRecord0;
  Table[1] := @Record1;
  fTempTable[1] := @TempRecord1;
  Table[2] := @Record2;
  fTempTable[2] := @TempRecord2;
  Table[3] := @Record3;
  fTempTable[3] := @TempRecord3;
  Table[4] := @Record4;
  fTempTable[4] := @TempRecord4;
  Table[5] := @Record5;
  fTempTable[5] := @TempRecord5;
  Table[6] := @Record6;
  fTempTable[6] := @TempRecord6;
  Table[7] := @Record7;
  fTempTable[7] := @TempRecord7;
  for i := 0 to 7 do
  begin
    Table[i]^.Something := i;
  end;
  ShowTable( Table, Memo1 );
  CopyTable;
  fTempTable[ 5 ].Something := 73;
  ShowTable( fTempTable, Memo2 );
  ShowTable( Table, Memo3 );
end;

procedure TForm2.ShowTable(const ATable: TTable; const AMemo: TMemo);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  AMemo.Clear;
  for i := 0 to 7 do
  begin
    AMemo.Lines.Add( IntToStr( ATable[i]^.Something));
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try this. I thought I could copy these values ​​using AllocMem or something like that and free after using.

Comment: Note that if `TRecord` contains dynamic arrays, a copy operation is shallow.

Comment: @Mlody87 yes, you can. I was just illustrating the principle. How you create and destroy your temporary objects/records is up to you. Personally I tend to use objects rather than records, with Create and Free, but it depends on the situation. The central point really is that you do need to create your temporary objects, you can't just copy the pointers.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Mlody87: the best way to do this is to use New(). That will initialize the records properly. And free them using Dispose(), since that will finalize properly. That is important if the record contains "managed" types.